# How to execute a command for each file in a deep directory structure, recursively?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a deep directory structure, with a large number of files (about 1M).  I'd like to execute a command against each. (In my case the files are pngs which I'd like to run optipng against.)

I've tried this:

```
find . -name *.png | xargs sudo optipng -o2
```

but am getting the error `argument list too long`.

I'm assuming that xargs should be able to handle this, and that there must be a problem with my syntax.

Comment: Caution: If your *current* directory contains PNG files, the shell will expand `*.png` to their names - thus doubly defeating the purpose of the command (not matching all `.png` files, and possibly causing an `argument list too long` for `find` itself. Always quote things you want to pass as-is: `find . -iname '*.png' | ...`

Answer (score 7):

Do the exec directly with find rather than via xargs.

```
sudo find . -name '*.png' -exec optipng -o {} +
```

Comment: Thanks.  Will that execute the optipng as sudo though?  I've tried `sudo find` with xargs, and it didn't  (I had to put the sudo next to xargs) [not my downvote btw]

Comment: Yes the `find` gets run as root and it spawns `optipng` which because it is being spawned by a process owned by root will also run as root.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to get it to spawn n parallel processes?  (e.g. with xargs you can do this with the -P switch)

Comment: You should quote `*.png`. Otherwise, if there are any PNG files in the current directory, it will be expanded to them.

Answer (score 4):

Using sudo as command to execute by `xargs` isn't working, as you see. Try it the other way around:

```
find . -name '*.png' | sudo xargs optipng -o2
```

The difference is that your version creates a command like

```
 sudo optipng -o2 file1 file2 file3 file4 ......
```

and sudo can't handle so many parameters.

Doing it the other way around executes sudo once, which in turn starts `xargs` which then generates a command like

```
optipng -o2 file1 file2 file3 file4 ......
```

and if `optipng` can handle many files as parameters, it should work.

If that still doesn't work, you will have to use `-exec` instead like in Geraint's answer, but this should be your last resort.

Comment: BTW - why would -exec be a last resort?  (not familiar with it, so just curious)

Comment: `-exec` spawns a new `optipng` process for every file, while `xargs` tries to feed as many files as possible to one instance. If `optipng` can handle many parameters, this is much more effective.

Comment: He says 1M files, bash is the guy thats saying `argument list too long` not `optipng` or `sudo`. Your only option if you really have 1 million files is to use `-exec`

Comment: @GeraintJones: No, because it's precisely the job of `xargs` to make sure this doesn't happen.

Comment: Thats a good point.

Comment: If the `-exec` command is terminated with a `+` instead of a `;` then find will group the files into groups small enough to avoid the "Argument list too long" error. (You must also provide a `{}` argument before the `+` which will be replaced by the filename list.) This feature wasn't in the original unix `find`, but it's been around long enough (in POSIX for over 10 years)... it's time to unlearn the use of `xargs`.

Comment: You need to quote `*.png` in case there are any matching files in the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another shot at this:

`find . -name '*.png' | sudo xargs -n x -P y optipng -o2`

Which will start one optipng for `x` files and `y` such processes in parallel (might help you get things done faster if you have some cores to spare).
Having `x` greater than 10 probably won't have great impact on performance.

That will help keep the argument list short. So you could probably move `sudo` to where you had it, but that's just another command that would have to be run for every batch.